# XSLT transformation from unstructured to structure element

Tags: xslt, transformation

I want to use XSLT to transform a machine generated policy element into a collection party elements in an insurance_policy_group element. Each element in the policy element should be represented as a party element in the insurance_policy_group.  The number of policy_holders in a policy is unbounded and so are the legal_reps and main_claimant. The machine that generates the XML uses a letter/number suffix to generate an element if there are more than one. It's a 3rd party API so I only know that policy_holder. legal_rep elements will either have a number or letter suffix at the end. For example if there are 2 policy holders the policy element might contain policy_holder_1 and policy_holder_a. Please scroll down to see output

My goal is to transform the  element into the  element.  For every policy_holder or legal_rep I need to create a party element in the insurance_party_group. Please remember that the policy XML is machine generated and hence may look odd. I have only done basic transformations in XSLT unfortunately.

```
<!--  Machine generated XML from calling a service, this should be used
 for the transformation -->
<policy>
  <policy_holder>Dan Glover</policy_holder>
  <policy_holder_address1>4 Lemming Street</policy_holder_address1>
  <policy_holder_address2></policy_holder_address2>
  <policy_holder_city>Dickinson</policy_holder_city>
  <policy_holder_state>ND</policy_holder_state>
  <policy_holder_zip>551221</policy_holder_zip>

   <policy_holder_1>Sherie Glover</policy_holder_1>
   <policy_holder_address1__1>4 Lemming Street</policy_holder_address1_1>
   <policy_holder_address2_1>Dickinson</policy_holder_address2_1>
   <policy_holder_city_1></policy_holder_city_1>
   <policy_holder_state_1>ND</policy_holder_state_1>
   <policy_holder_zip_1>551221<policy_holder_zip_1>

   <main_claimaint_b>Sherie Glover</main_claimaint_b>
   <main_claimaint_address1__b>4 Lemming Street</main_claimaint_address1_b>
   <main_claimaint_address2_b>Dickinson</main_claimaint_address2_b>
   <main_claimaint_city_b></main_claimaint_city_b>
   <main_claimaint_state_b>ND</main_claimaint_state_b>
   <main_claimaintr_zip_b>551221<main_claimaint_zip_b>

   <legal_rep_a>Major Parksinson</legal_rep_a>
   <legal_rep_address1__a>4511 Durham  Road</legal_rep_address1_a>
   <legal_rep_address2_a>Dickinson</legal_rep_address2_a>
   <legal_rep_city_a></legal_rep_city_a>
   <legal_rep_state_a>ND</legal_rep_state_a>
   <legal_rep_zip_a>55124<legal_rep_zip_a>

   <legal_rep_1>Tom Lynch/legal_rep_1>
   <legal_rep_address1__1>44511 Durham  Road</legal_rep_address1_1>
   <legal_rep_address2_1>Dickinson</legal_rep_address2_1>
   <legal_rep_city_1></legal_rep_city_1>
   <legal_rep_state_1>ND</legal_rep_state_1>
   <legal_rep_zip_1>551221<legal_rep_zip_1>
   </policy> 

   <!-- Expected output, the result of applying a stylesheet on the machine 
       generated XML above -->
   <insurance_party_group>
    <party>
      <name>Dan Glover</Name>
      <addressText1>4 Lemming Street</addressText1>
     <addressText2></addressText2>
     <city>Dickinson</city>
     <state>ND</state>
     <zipCode>551221</zipCode>
     <participant_type>CLAIMANT</participant_type>
  </party>

  <party>
    <name>Sherie Glover</Name>
    <addressText1>4 Lemming Street</addressText1>
    <addressText2></addressText2>
    <city>Dickinson</city>
    <state>ND</state>
    <zipCode>551221</zipCode>
    <participant_type>PRINCIPAL_CLAIMANT</participant_type>
  </party>

  <party>
    <name>Major Parksinson</Name>
     <addressText1>4511 Durham  Road</addressText1>
    <addressText2></addressText2>
    <city>Dickinson</city>
    <state>ND</state>
    <zipCode>55124</zipCode>
    <participant_type>LEGAL</participant_type>
  </party>

  <party>
    <name>Tom Lynch</Name>
    <addressText1>4511 Durham  Road</addressText1>
    <addressText2></addressText2>
    <city>Dickinson</city>
     <state>ND</state>
     <zipCode>55124</zipCode>
     <participant_type>LEGAL</participant_type>
    </party>
 </insurance_party_group>
```

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. Please explain the **logic** that needs to be applied here.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to add more context.

Comment: Even better is to show desired result and any attempted script.

Comment: I have stated very clearly the desired result is the <insurance_party_group> <party>...</party> as a result of transforming <policy><policy_holder></policy> what is not clear about that?

Comment: No Worries: Just an update I have solved the problem, just needed to get to speed with XSLT a little more.